# Pull most recent firestore rules to local

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, firebase-cli

I am deploying rules to Firestore using `firebase deploy --only firestore`

Is there a way to pull the most recent rules (to stay in-sync), e.g. in case I or somebody else has made changes through the web UI.

Something along the lines of `firebase pull --only firestore` ?

Comment: Please let me know what more information you are looking for and I will try to help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

As far the documentations ,no direct way to sync the these.However you can use the [Method: projects.rulesets.list](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rest/v1/projects.rulesets/list) , which will List Ruleset metadata only and optionally filter the results by Ruleset name and the [Method: projects.rulesets.get](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rest/v1/projects.rulesets/get) will get a Ruleset by name including the full Source contents.

The rulesets.list method will list all of them, most recent at the top and rulesets.get method will get you the content when you provide the name/id from the list.

Comment: Thanks. Not quite what I am looking for but appreciate sharing your thoughts